# MSMQ Outbound Queue Stuck After System Recovery

Tags: nservicebus, msmq, msdtc

I have an outbound queue on a server with messages in a processed but "unacknowledged state". New messages in entering the queue are suspended in the same manner. The issue started happening when the sending server was recovered from a backup. For a brief time, there was also a DTC connectivity issue that was since subsequently resolved. I do see some transactions in the DTC transaction list with a status of "only failed to notify" - i am unsure if these are related, but it seems likely. Any thoughts on troubleshooting this condition?

I believe the condition is queue specific. There are other queues with the same sender/destination that are working correctly.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a queue permission issue/firewall/DTC

Comment: How was the server recovered? Was it a complete recovery from a system image backup?

Comment: we finally did a sysprep and things started moving. It was recovered from a virtual image.